# monaco-editor get column and line number by index in `model.getValue()`

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a way to get the position in form of `{column: ..., lineNumber: ...}` from the index in the editor's value?

For instance, if `model.getValue() == "line1\nline2"`, then I want to get `{column: 1, lineNumber 0}` if index equals to 6 (it is the index of character `l` in the second line).

It is not hard to implement, but I'm asking if this functionality already exists in monaco-editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two APIs in `ITextModel`, which are named `getOffsetAt` and `getPositionAt`, which convert a position to a character index (offset) and vice versa.